# Hölder norm estimates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

How do you prove the following estimate for composition of functions:

If $k\geq 1$, then there exists a constant $c=c(k,\alpha)$ such that 
$$
\|f_1\circ g_1-f_2\circ g_2\|_{k,\alpha}\leq c\left(1+\|\nabla g_1\|_{k-1,\alpha}+\|\nabla g_2\|_{k-1,\alpha}\right)^{k+1}\\
\bigg[\|f_1-f_2\|_{k,\alpha}+\min\big\{\|\nabla f_1\|_{k,\alpha},\|\nabla f_2\|_{k,\alpha}\big\} \|g_1-g_2\|_{k,\alpha}\bigg].
$$

for functions $f$ and $g$ suffiently regular for everything to make sense.  Here, the norms are the Holder norms and seminorms (i.e. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should be able to do this from the observation that
$$|(f \circ g) (x) - (f\circ g)(y)| \leq |f'(\xi)| |g(x) - g(y)|$$ if $f$ is $C^1$ for some $\xi$ along the line joining $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Hi Ray, I actually don't see how the result follows from that.  Could you say a bit more?